# Load test raw ssl/tls

Tags: performance, ssl, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to load-test my raw tls server. I try jmeter, but it seems no ssl/tls sampler available(only bundled with http). How can i load - test raw ssl with jmeter? Or maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Can you not use the HTTP sampler?

Comment: No, my server use raw bytestream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Java Client available for your GOST TLS then your best option is to extend:

https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/AbstractJavaSamplerClient.html

And use Java Request Sampler that will show your implementation in select box:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request

See :

- http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2011/09/how-to-create-a-java-class-performance-test-using-jmeters-abstractjavasamplerclient/

Comment: Awesome! Big thanks! I think you save my week. It's so important, to dig in right direction. I'll try to implement it now.